# Beltrami Equation - Quasiconformal Map Injectivity

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations

For context, I am currently working through Alhfor's Lectures on Quasiconformal Mapping - specifically, the Measurable Riemann Mapping Theorem. Source to the material can be found here: https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/lectures-on-quasiconformal-mappings-ahlfors.pdf. The issue I am currently having is on page 97.

Specifically, I am stuck on showing that if $f$ satisfies the following equation:
[image]

Then $f$ is injective. Is there something about this equation that illuminates the injectivity property to any of you?

For those who are unfamiliar with the notation, I believe we can just think of $K_p (1-kC_p)^{-1-2/p}$ as a constant and $\mu$ is the Beltrami coefficient of $f \in L^p$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$ then the right-hand side is zero, so the left-hand side must be zero as well, which implies $z_1 = z_2$. – Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: oh yea, you're right. how did I not see that. thank you.